# ¿Cómo excluir caracteres al exportar una tabla mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla de la cual exporto un registro/fila especifico de una tabla, dentro de mi base de datos, pero al momento de abrir el archivo, me doy cuenta que algunos campos del registros que exporte tiene el caracter de comillas dobles ***"***, por ejemplo, cuando se trata de un monitor e indican sus pulgadas.

¿Cómo pudiera excluir ese caracter para que no afecte la saluda resultante de mi archivo?

Les dejo mi código donde hago la conexion, indico la tabla, realiza el query para esta con la fila especifica y la exporta.

Nota: la página php anterior a esta, envia una variable con el id para indicar qué fila desea exportar.

Se me ocurre hacer la exclusión en la función del query pero no se cómo.

```
<?php
$db_name     = "bd";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_link     = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$table = "articulos";

function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}
function query_whole_table($table, $value = '*'){
    $id_articulo=$_GET['art'];
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table where id_articulo='$id_articulo'";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}

$export = '"Id","Nombre","Descripcion","Proveedor","Cantidad","Numero de serie","Categoria","id_pedido","id_usuario","Empresa","Ubicacion","Codigo de barras"'."\n";
$result = query_whole_table($table);

foreach($result as $record){
  $export .= '"'.implode('","',$record) .'"'."\n";
}
// output the file 
// we can set a header to send it directly to the browser
file_put_contents($table.".csv", $export);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\""."articulos.csv"."\"");  
echo $export; exit;
?>
```

Gracias

Comment: El método que estás utilizando tiene serios problemas de seguridad. Quizás esta publicación responda a tu pregunta, cubriendo esos problemas: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Comment: de acuerdo, lo revisare, aunque este es un sistema antiguo que se esta actualizando, incluso necesita instalarse una nueva version de php y mas servidores independientes para otros servicios. Pero al ser local, no se pudiera hacer esa exclusion del caracter, como solucion 'momentanea'?

Answer (score 1):

Las comillas dobles se *saltean* (? en inglés es *escape*) poniendo al lado otra comilla doble.

Es decir, `"` pasa a `""`.

Si puedes modificar tu consulta podrías utilizar la función de MySQL [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). En este caso:

```
REPLACE (NombreColumna, '"', '""')
```

También podrías hacerlo en PHP,con [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php). Opciones:

**1) Usando str_replace director**

```
$record= str_replace('"','""',$record);
```

**2) str_replace + foreach**

```
foreach ($record as &$valor) {
    $valor = str_replace('"','""',$valor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estás usando mysql, el cual se considera obsoleto, usa mysqli, las sentencias son casi iguales y no complica mucho el cambio. Y si crees podrías necesitar usar más tipos de bases de datos diferentes a mysqli usa entonces PDO

Comment: Fijate que ese es lo que le comenta Mariano en la pregunta. Lo cual kenethluna ha dicho que hará en cuanto pueda, de mientras necesita una respuesta para salvar su problema. ¿Tienes una posible solución concreta al problema? Si es así, edita tu pregunta y agregala.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función [`msqli_real_scape_string($loQueQuierasLimpiar)`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Hola @Batu157. ¿Podrías agregar una breve descripción de cómo esta función solucionaría el problema, quizás mostrando dónde debería usarla en el código? Un usuario que recién empieza a programar en PHP podría no comprender del todo a qué te estás refiriendo.